# How can i overwrite file from vendor so that setup:di:compile won't read it

Tags: setup-di-compile, deprecated

I have a 3rd party module that is giving some deprecation issues.
Is there any way to replace the class that is having problems in my own module in app/code without moving the whole module from vendor?
I have tried creating module and writing preference for that class, adding the problematic file in main composer.jsons autoload['files'] section but setup:di:compile still fails as it loads all classes even if not loaded in the project by autoloader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be to use a patch via composer.

You could generate a patch for the class to make it compatible, basically create a diff on the original class and the new compatible class with your changes, then apply it as a composer patch. It keeps it cleaner with the idea (i hope) that the 3rd party eventually provide a compatible version themselves!

Example:

Some Incompatible class at `vendor/third-party/module-name/Model/SomeIncompatibleClass.php` has some incompatible inheritance or something along those lines:

```
...
    public function __construct(
        SomeInjection $someInjection,
        SomeOtherInjection $someOtherInjection
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $someInjection,
            $someOtherInjection
        );
    }
...
```

where the class it's extending now has a 3rd required argument for its constructor. We just want to change this to add the dependancy to our class and pass it through to the parent call.

One way to patch it (and there are a few ways, probably better ways) is to:

- Create a new folder outside of your project
- Copy this file to the new folder
- Initialise the new folder with git `git init`
- Stage the incompatible version of the file with git `git add SomeIncompatibleClass.php`
- Make your changes for compatibility or whatever
- Generate a git diff `git diff > mypatch.patch`

This will leave you with a patch file of a git diff with the top like:

```
diff --git a/SomeIncompatibleClass.php b/SomeIncompatibleClass.php
index 5aa4e53..97c2142 100644
--- a/SomeIncompatibleClass.php
+++ b/SomeIncompatibleClass.php
@@ -33,7 +33,7 @@ class SomeIncompatibleClass
...
```

We need to take this file and update the paths to the file to match the vendor path to the file so changing `SomeIncompatibleClass.php` to `vendor/third-party/module-name/Model/SomeIncompatibleClass.php` so it starts like:

```
diff --git a/vendor/third-party/module-name/Model/SomeIncompatibleClass.php b/vendor/third-party/module-name/Model/SomeIncompatibleClass.php
index 5aa4e53..97c2142 100644
--- a/vendor/third-party/module-name/Model/SomeIncompatibleClass.php
+++ b/vendor/third-party/module-name/Model/SomeIncompatibleClass.php
@@ -33,7 +33,7 @@ class SomeIncompatibleClass
...
```

Now you have a patch you can apply with composer using something like -https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches - where you can create a patches folder in your magento root, and add some configuration to the composer.json (all in the composer-patches docs) then when you run `composer update` and the likes, it will apply your patch to the file using the diff/patch you generated and your third party class will be compatible!

There might be better options, I just saw your question and thought this would be a way around it.